# BASH- string assignment with a string name containing a variable

Tags: string, bash

I have been going crazy trying to figure out this syntax...can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#Counter to iterate through the ENTIRE affinity array
affArrayCtr=0

#Counter to go through 4 cores for EACH pid     
affCtr=0

#Counter to go through each PID to keep track of which PID we are on
pidCtr=0

#Affinity array size
affArraySz=${#affConfigArray[@]}

#Each core's new affinity, strings initialized to empty
pid0Aff=
pid1Aff=
pid2Aff=
pid3Aff=

while [ $affArrayCtr -lt $affArraySz ]; do

        while [ $affCtr -lt $NUMCORES ]; do

                if [[ ${affConfigArray[$affArrayCtr]} -eq 1 ]]; then
                        tempAff0="$(pid"${pidCtr}"Aff)"
                        tempAff1=$(($affArrayCtr % 4))
                        pid${pidCtr}Aff="$tempAff0 $tempAff1"

                        affCtr=$(($affCtr + 1))
                        affArrayCtr=$(($affArrayCtr + 1))
                fi

                affArrayCtr=$(($affArrayCtr + 1))
                affCtr=$(($affCtr + 1))
        done

        affCtr=0
        pidCtr=$(($pidCtr + $NUMCORES))


done

echo "Final affinity strings before adding the commas"
echo $pid0Aff
```

The problem is where I try to assign `tempAff0="$(pid"${pidCtr}"Aff)"` and when I try to do a final concatenation `pid${pidCtr}Aff="$tempAff0 $tempAff1"`.

I attempted to make the change where I use arrays instead of strings, however, I am still having an issue with the fact that my array name contains a variable:

```
#Each core's new affinity, arrays initialized to empty
declare -a pid0Aff
declare -a pid1Aff
declare -a pid2Aff
declare -a pid3Aff

while [ $affArrayCtr -lt $affArraySz ]; do

        affCtr=0

        while [ $affCtr -lt $NUMCORES ]; do

                if [[ ${affConfigArray[$affArrayCtr]} -eq 1 ]]; then

                        tempAff=$(($affArrayCtr % 4))
                        pid${pidCtr}Aff[${#pid${pidCtr}Aff[*]}]="$tempAff"

                        affCtr=$(($affCtr + 1))
                        affArrayCtr=$(($affArrayCtr + 1))
                fi
```

The culprit is here where I want to append to the array:

```
pid${pidCtr}Aff[${#pid${pidCtr}Aff[*]}]="$tempAff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution: instead of trying to dynamically create a variable name, replace your individual varialbes `pid0Aff`, `pid1Aff`, etc with an array(e.g., `pidAff`), and use pidCtr to index it.

This should put you on the right track:

```
#! /bin/bash
pidAff[0]='zero'
pidAff[1]='one'
pidAff[2]='two'
pidAff[3]='three'

pidAffArrayCtr=0
pidAffArraySz=4

while [ $pidAffArrayCtr -lt $pidAffArraySz ]; do
    echo "pidAff of $pidAffArrayCtr is ${pidAff[$pidAffArrayCtr]}"
    pidAffArrayCtr=$(($pidAffArrayCtr + 1))
done
```

Comment: So I attempted this solution, and am still having an issue with having a variable in my array name.  I declare an array and have an issue here:

Answer (score 0):

Use BASH indirection as:

```
echo "${!tempAff0} ${!tempAff1}"
```